# Editar usuário do ActiveDirectory com C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

Olá, estou tentando adicionar as iniciais dos funcionários da empresa no parâmetro iniciais do usuário do AD e ao tentar executar o mesmo me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'O atributo ou valor do serviço de diretório especificado já existe. '
```

poderiam me ajudar?

```
// Lê o resultado da query SQL Server
SqlDataReader sdr = scm.ExecuteReader();

Classes.ActiveDirectory AD = new Classes.ActiveDirectory();

// Percorre todos os resultados da query e coloca na ListView
while (sdr.Read())
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sdr.GetString(3)))
    {

        // Realizando a consulta no AD
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(AD.abreConexaoAD());
        // Enviando uma Query para o AD
        //ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(mail=" + sdr.GetString(3) + "))";
        ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(sAMAccountName=api.teste))";
        // Retorna o resultado
        SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

        if (rs != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = rs.GetDirectoryEntry();
            directoryEntry.Properties["initials"].Add(sdr.GetString(0));

            //MessageBox.Show(directoryEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());

            // Salvando as alterações
            directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
            directoryEntry = null;

        }

    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

}
```

Comment: Qual a definição de AD?

Comment: ActiveDirectory

Comment: Não é porque você está abrindo várias conexões com o AD? uma a cada iteração do seu while?

Comment: Pois é @LeandroAngelo, como que fecho a conexão? Sou iniciante e devo estar fazendo alguma coisa errada ou esquecendo de algo.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz as seguintes alterações se sucesso.

```
Classes.ActiveDirectory AD = new Classes.ActiveDirectory();
// Realizando a consulta no AD
DirectoryEntry openConection = AD.abreConexaoAD();

//// Realizando a consulta no AD
//DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(AD.abreConexaoAD());

// Percorre todos os resultados da query e coloca na ListView
while (sdr.Read())
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sdr.GetString(3)))
    {

        //// Realizando a consulta no AD
        //DirectoryEntry openConection = AD.abreConexaoAD();
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(openConection);
        // Enviando uma Query para o AD
        //ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(mail=" + sdr.GetString(3) + "))";
        ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(sAMAccountName=api.teste))";
        // Retorna o resultado
        SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

        if (rs != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = rs.GetDirectoryEntry();
            directoryEntry.Properties["initials"].Add(sdr.GetString(0));

            //MessageBox.Show(directoryEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());

            // Salvando as alterações
            directoryEntry.CommitChanges();

        }


    }


}

openConection.Close();
```